# HTML ordered list 1.1, 1.2 (Nested counters and scope) not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I use nested counters and scope to create an ordered list:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
li {
    display: block
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <ol>
        <li>two.one</li>
        <li>two.two</li>
        <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
    <li>three</li>
    <ol>
        <li>three.one</li>
        <li>three.two</li>
        <ol>
            <li>three.two.one</li>
            <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

I expect the following outcome:

```
1. one
2. two
  2.1. two.one
  2.2. two.two
  2.3. two.three
3. three
  3.1 three.one
  3.2 three.two
    3.2.1 three.two.one
    3.2.2 three.two.two
4. four
```

Instead, this is what I see **(wrong numbering)**:

```html
1. one
2. two
  2.1. two.one
  2.2. two.two
  2.3. two.three
2.4 three <!-- this is where it goes wrong, when going back to the parent -->
  2.1 three.one
  2.2 three.two
    2.2.1 three.two.one
    2.2.2 three.two.two
2.3 four
```

I have no clue, does anyone see where it goes wrong?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGCUk/2/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Uncheck "normalize CSS"  - http://jsfiddle.net/qGCUk/3/
The CSS reset used in that defaults all list margins and paddings to 0

**UPDATE** http://jsfiddle.net/qGCUk/4/  - you have to include your sub-lists in your main `<li>`

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How to make its index's followed with point - like `1.` > `1.1.` `1.2.` `1.3.` and so on ?

Comment: Just be sure to fix the css selectors so it doesn't affect things like navigation lists.

Comment: @Okomikeruko What does it mean to "fix the css selectors"? Because I'm running in exactly the problem you alluded to - this trick not just affecting the numbered list I want to use it for but the other lists in my HTML as well. :-\

Nevermind: Moshe Simantov's answer fixes that. :)

Comment: @antred element attributes like `id` and `class` allow you to define css specific to those elements with selectors. If you use a blanket `li`, `ul`, `ol` etc, then the css affects all instances of it. But if you set your element to `<ol class="cleared">` and your css selector to `ol.cleared`, then you don't affect other `ol` elements unnecessarily.

Comment: Why is the li display: block here?

Comment: This is such an ugly, hacky way. This method doesn't even keep the text to the right of the numbers; the text comes over to the number after the first line. It's not your fault though. It's so disappointing that CSS doesn't have a way to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 79):

Use this style to change only the nested lists:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
    counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol > li {
    display: block;
}

ol ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Great! Worked out-of-the box for me! Toda.

Comment: This is the best answer as it also has the first level with a point and inset the content.

Comment: if I add `font-weight: bold` to `ol ol > li:before` the nested list's counters are `bold` but it doesn't make the counters of the first level list `bold`?

Comment: To make this work tidily for me I had to add `float: left;` to the `:before`

Comment: a decade later still usefull. thank you

Answer (score 17):

**Check this out :**

http://jsfiddle.net/PTbGc/

Your issue seems to have been fixed.

---

What shows up for me (under Chrome and Mac OS X)

```
1. one
2. two
  2.1. two.one
  2.2. two.two
  2.3. two.three
3. three
  3.1 three.one
  3.2 three.two
    3.2.1 three.two.one
    3.2.2 three.two.two
4. four
```

---

#### How I did it

---

**Instead of :**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
   <ol>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
   </ol>
```

**Do :**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2
   <ol>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
   </ol>
</li>
```

Answer (score 10):

I think that these answers are over-complicating this. If you don't need to support Internet Explorer, then the solution is a one-liner:

```css
ol > li::marker { content: counters(list-item, '.') '. '; }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <ol>
        <li>two.one</li>
        <li>two.two</li>
        <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
    <li>three</li>
    <ol>
        <li>three.one</li>
        <li>three.two</li>
        <ol>
            <li>three.two.one</li>
            <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

See the [`::marker` CSS pseudo-element page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) and the [Using CSS counters page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) on MDN's CSS reference website for more information.

Answer (score 8):

This is a great solution! With a few additional CSS rules you can format it just like an MS Word outline list with a hanging first line indent:

```
OL { 
  counter-reset: item; 
}
LI { 
  display: block; 
}
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") "."; 
  counter-increment: item; 
  padding-right:10px; 
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that you can't copy the list numbers. So if you copy huge list it will be without numbers

Comment: Great !  Exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 7):

## Keep it Simple!

This is a Simpler and Standard solution to increment the number and to retain the dot at the end.
Even if you get the CSS right, it will not work if your HTML is not correct. see below.

### CSS

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol li {
  display: block;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ". ") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

### SASS

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    li {
        display: block;
        &:before {
            content: counters(item, ". ") ". ";
            counter-increment: item
        }
    }
}
```

### HTML Parent Child

If you add the child make sure it is under the parent `li`.

#### Will not work ✘

Notice the parent `li` and the child `ol li` are individual here, this will not work.

```html
<ol>
    <li>Parent 1</li> <!-- Parent has open and close li tags -->
    <ol> 
        <li>Child</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Parent 2</li>
</ol>
```

#### Will work ✔

You need to place the `ol li` child element inside parent `li`. Notice the parent `li` is hugging the child.

```html
<ol>

    <li>Parent 1 <!-- Parent open li tag -->
        <ol> 
            <li>Child</li>
        </ol>
    </li> <!-- Parent close li tag -->

    <li>Parent 2</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4):

After going through other answers I came up with this, just apply class `nested-counter-list` to root `ol` tag:

**sass code:**

```
ol.nested-counter-list {
  counter-reset: item;

  li {
    display: block;

    &::before {
      content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
      counter-increment: item;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  ol {
    counter-reset: item;

    & > li {
      display: block;

      &::before {
        content: counters(item, ".") " ";
        counter-increment: item;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**css code**:

```
ol.nested-counter-list {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol.nested-counter-list li {
  display: block;
}
ol.nested-counter-list li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ol.nested-counter-list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol.nested-counter-list ol > li {
  display: block;
}
ol.nested-counter-list ol > li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```css
ol.nested-counter-list {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.nested-counter-list li {
  display: block;
}

ol.nested-counter-list li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.nested-counter-list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.nested-counter-list ol>li {
  display: block;
}

ol.nested-counter-list ol>li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol class="nested-counter-list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

And if you need trailing `.` at the end of the nested list's counters use this:

```css
ol.nested-counter-list {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.nested-counter-list li {
  display: block;
}

ol.nested-counter-list li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.nested-counter-list ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
```

```html
<ol class="nested-counter-list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is the right solution that works proper with nested-counter-list class encapsulation within larger css files

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem recently. The fix is to set the display property of the li items in the ordered list to list-item, and not display block, and ensure that the display property of ol is not list-item. i.e

```
li { display: list-item;}
```

With this, the html parser sees all li as the list item and assign the appropriate value to it, and sees the ol, as an inline-block or block element based on your settings, and doesn't try to assign any count value to it.

Comment: This duplicates the numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Moshe's solution is great but the problem may still exist if you need to put the list inside a `div`. (read: [CSS counter-reset on nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539617/css-counter-reset-on-nested-list))

This style could prevent that issue:

```css
ol > li {
    counter-increment: item;
}

ol > li:first-child {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol ol > li {
    display: block;
}

ol ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>list not nested in div</li>
</ol>

<hr>

<div>
  <ol>
  <li>nested in div</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

You can also set the counter-reset on `li:before`.

Comment: what if I don't want the trailing `.` in the nested list but the root list?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone above for their answers!

As I needed RTL solution, I found out that this can solve it:

```
ol.nested-counter-list li {
  display: block;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

So you would use any of the solution above, but also update the specific CSS selector for RTL cases.