# <ol> sub-section with <p> in its <li>'s

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working/10405962#10405962) question , and according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405962/831294) answer .

I try to make same list **but** with `<p>...</p>` wraped in each `<li>` , seems it works but my problem is that it break a line for each `<li>` .

Here it with NO `<p>` - http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/tv5fV/ ,

and here it with the `<p>` - http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/2ANwJ/1/

How to make the 2nd (with `<p>`) to be looks like the 1st (no `<p>`)  ?

Preferably answers with just css edit , but jQuery also would be acceptable .

Comment: Why do you want a paragraph in your list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline` for your `<p>` tags:

```
li p {display:inline}
```

Making it 'inline' will remove the line break since it will no longer be a block-level element and also it will get rid of the margins that browsers use by default for `<p>` tags.

See this [Updated and working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ANwJ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block;` for the `<p>` tag.

By default, `<p>` tags are set as `display:block;`, which will break your content to a new line. espacially when you use content using `:before`

http://jsfiddle.net/2ANwJ/7/

```
li > p { 
    display: inline; 
}
```

Comment: you need to reset the padding and margin to 0 as well if ur using inline-block

Comment: no, that is not what was asked. so this is additional styling

Comment: or, well, you are right. he says like 1st... i´ll update