# Nested counters HTML list 1 1.1 a i - is this possible

Tags: css

I have a convoluted nested ordered list that I need to implement which looks like this:

```
1. one
2. two
    2.1 two.one
    2.2 two.two
    2.3 two.three
3. three
    3.1 three.one
    3.2 three.two
        a. lower-alpha-a
        b. lower-alpha-b
            i. lower-numeral-i
            ii. lower-numberal-ii
4. four
```

I have tried this with css counters but I cant get the increment to stop after the first level, it goes all the way through to the last level.

## CSS

```
OL {
    counter-reset: item
}
LI {
    display: block
}
LI:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two</li>
      <ol type="a">
        <li>three.two.one</li>
        <li>three.two.two
          <ol type="i">
            <li>three.two.one</li>
            <li>three.two.two</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/902fLnt7/2/
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working

Comment: sorry don't think its a duplicate. I am looking for a solution for a different list-style on the nested lists , so that makes it different from the link. ta

Comment: @tech_hoodwink show us your html code. it is hard to give answer without it.

Comment: added the html and jsfiddle link @Mr_Green thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slightly different to the linked answer.

Firstly, there is a wrongly nested ordered list in your questions HTML. The closing tag of `<li>three.two</li>` should wrap `<ol type="a">`

We need to remove the content for lower levels with:

```
ol li li li:before {
  display: none;
}
```

Change the counter slightly for the second level:

```
ol li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

and give our lower levels their styles (the list style should be consistent, so no need for classes):

```
ol li li li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
/* Every step down from here will take this property */
ol li li li li {
  list-style: lower-roman;
}
```

Of course, we can override with classes, for one level, if really needed:

```
ol.alpha li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
```

### Complete Example

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
ol li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
ol li li li:before {
  display: none;
}
ol li li li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
/* Every step down from here will take this property */

ol li li li li {
  list-style: lower-roman;
}
/* Override with classes */

ol.alpha li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two
            <ol>
              <li>three.two.one</li>
              <li>three.two.two

                <ol>
                  <li>three.two.one</li>
                  <li>three.two.two
                    <ol>
                      <li>three.two.one</li>
                      <li>three.two.two
                        <ol class="alpha">
                          <li>three.two.one</li>
                          <li>three.two.two</li>
                        </ol>
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Seems to work but I wonder about how easily it can get out of hand if you have many levels nested (and maybe some are to be one style while others at the same nested level not)

Comment: I've added a ridiculous amount of nested items to my answer. They will take the style from the most li's (in this case `ol li li li li`, so we have roman numerals) **You can always override with a class if you really want to :)**

Comment: thanks a lot @misterManSam this is great and makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new counter for each level seemed to do the trick

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/902fLnt7/4/)**

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
.a li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)". ";
}
.i li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman)". ";
}
li {
    display: block;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
.a li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-alpha)". ";
}
.i li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman)". ";
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol class="a">
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two
            <ol class="i">
              <li>three.two.one</li>
              <li>three.two.two</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```