# CSS counter-reset on nested list

Tags: css, css-counter

I'm struggling with `counter-reset` when ol is in div.
Red list in the snippet numbering should be:

> 1, 2, 3

not:

> 3.1, 
>   3.2,
>   3.3,

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD
        <ol>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<div>
    <ol style="color:red;">
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1dab8xs7/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your issue isn't with the `counter-reset` property, it is with the content property and the `counters()` function. This function atomaticaly adds a new instance for each nested element. This is great for the nested `ol` elements but it also adds a counter instance when the first level `ol` is nested in any other element.

So you should use the `counter()` function on the first level `ol` elements and keep the `counters()` (notice the "s") function on the second level one  :

More info on MDN about [nesting counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters#Nesting_counters)

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counter(item)". ";
}
ol ol li:before{
  content: counters(item,".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD
        <ol>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<div>
    <ol style="color:red;">
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

---

As suggested by [@harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry), you can also set the counter reset on the first child of the `ol` element, either with the `li:first-child` pseudo class or with the `ol::before` pseudo element, example :

```css
ol{
    list-style: none;
}
li:first-child{
    counter-reset: item;
}
/* or
ol:before {
    content: '';
    counter-reset: item;
}
*/
li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD
        <ol>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<div>
    <ol style="color:red;">
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the `div`
And "not reset" the `ol`
Like this:

```
<div style="color:red;counter-reset: item;">
    <ol style="color:red;counter-reset: none;" id="test">
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to work this around would be to add a class (since you cannot select an element based on what is its parent), and exclude it from initial selection with `:not` pseudo-class:

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD
        <ol>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
            <li>BBD</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<ol>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
    <li>BBD</li>
</ol>

<div>
    <ol class="x" style="color:red;">
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
        <li>BBD</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol:not(.x) {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
}
ol:not(.x) li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
}
```

as per [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/1dab8xs7/23/)