# Why are some sections of my contents blank?

Tags: html

I want to make a Contents list like this:

```
1.
2.
3.
    1.1
    1.2
        1.1.1
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
11.
```

However, when I open up the file the Contents turns out like this:

```
1. Blank
2. Item 
3. Item 
4. Item 
    1. Item 
    2. Item 
    3. Blank
        1. Item
4. Blank
5. Blank
    1. Item
    2. Item
    3. Item
    4. Item
    5. Item
```

My markup is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Contents</h2>
<div>
<ol>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-1">
        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
        </li>
    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-2">
        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
        </li>
    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-3">
        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
        <ol>
            <li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-4">
                <a href="#vres"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                </li>
            <li class="toclevel-2 tocsection-5">
                <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                </li>
            <li>
                <div style="margin-left: 2em">
                    <div>
                        <ol>
                            <li class="toclevel-3 tocsection-6">"#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                                </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                <span></span>
                <ol>
                    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-7">
                        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-8">
                        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-9">
                        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-10">
                        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="toclevel-1 tocsection-11">
                        <a href="#item"><span class="toctext">Item</span></a>
                        </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how I could go about resolving this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working

Comment: @MarcB Let's mark it as a duplicate, shall we?

Comment: Yes, granted my previous question was similar but I was anxious about it turning into a discussion on the comments, but this is the last issue I need resolved. Thanks