# How to create order list in order list?

Tags: css, html

I need create Order list in Order list in HTML.

For example:

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

This code not work in view.
How to create this view:

```
1. Coffee
2. Tea
    2-1. Black tea
    2-2. Green tea
3. Milk
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html ordered list 1.1, 1.2 (Nested counters and scope) not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working)

Comment: [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

Comment: @Pete , Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need a custom format for your nested list items, you'll need to use CSS counters.

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counter(item)". ";
}
ol ol li:before{
  content: counters(item,"-") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML does not have this styling by default. So we need to use some CSS here.

```css
OL { 
  counter-reset: item; 
}
LI { 
  display: block; 
}
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item; 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
   <ol>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

***Explanation:

"Counters" to count the li no.

"Counter-increment" to increment the counter every time a new li is detected.

and of course

"Counter-reset" to reset this counter every time a new sub-list (i.e ol is detected)***

### Hope this helps.

Comment: @KingReload I didn't ask the question buddy

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>This is</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>Nested list</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
    
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pseudo` element for this

```css
ol { 
    counter-reset: item 
}
li { 
    display: block 
}
li:before { 
    content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item; 
}
```

```html
 <ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
  <ol>
   <li>two.one</li>
   <li>two.two</li>
   <li>two.three</li>
  </ol>
     </li>
  <li>three 
  <ol>
   <li>three.one</li>
   <li>three.two</li>
    <ol>
     <li>three.two.one</li>
     <li>three.two.two</li>
    </ol>
   </ol>
     </li> 
  <li>four</li>
  </ol>
```