# Nested ordered list in kramdown

Tags: markdown, kramdown

Accordly to [kramdown documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#ordered-and-unordered-lists) the syntax for nested unordered lists (and also the result) is the following.

```
1. 1st item
2. 2nd item
   1. 1st sub-item of 2nd item
   2. 2nd sub-item of 2nd item
3. 3rd item
   1. 1st sub-item of 3rd item
   2. 2nd sub-item of 3rd item
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this instead?

```
1. 1st item
2. 2nd item
   2.1. 1st sub-item of 2nd item
   2.2. 2nd sub-item of 2nd item
3. 3rd item
   3.1. 1st sub-item of 3rd item
   3.2. 2nd sub-item of 3rd item
```

**Note:** I have to use kramdown, I cannot change it in favor of other markdown parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the question was wrong in the beginning since it is more a problem of CSS than kramdown. It was enough to change the CSS accordly to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working).

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
    counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol > li {
    display: block;
}

ol ol > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```