# HTML ordered list inside div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I formatted the ordered list with sub-items. Another `<ol>` is inside a `<div>` and the numbers are wrong; why?

```css
OL {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

LI {
  display: list-item
}

LI:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<hr />
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>one
      <ol>
        <li>one.one</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Please check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/PTbGc/1265/

Comment: have you ever check that? [Html ordered list 1.1, 1.2 (Nested counters and scope) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working)

Comment: In what way are the numbers '*wrong*'? What did you expect?

Comment: @uedemir that is not the same problem, the issue in that question is caused by invalid html in the nesting of one list, the problem with this question is that the second separate list is continuing from 2 instead of starting again from 1

Comment: Thanks @Pete, you saw it, also its not answered, not duplicate.

Comment: @mMo see the new duplicate I have linked to - that is you issue

Comment: @Pete yes, thats it, thanks, that works and i understand now

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate div tag for that. Check this snippets

```css
OL {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

LI {
  display: list-item
}

LI:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
    <div>
    <ol>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two
        <ol>
          <li>two.one</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
    </div>


    <hr />
    <div>
      <ol>
        <li>one
          <ol>
            <li>one.one</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use separate div tags

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
 <div>
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
 <div>
```