# Legal style list counters in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to format my lists in a legal style, I want to achieve something like this for my privacy policies and terms of use

```
1. Cookies 
    1.1 We use the following cookie 
       a) strictly necessary cookies 
       b) analytic cookies 
    1.2 You can block cookies 
    1.3 We may use third-party cookies
2. Collection of information
    2.1 For the purposes outlined in Clause 2, we may collect and process the following information about you:
       a) Information you give us
          (i) when you report any problem to us
          (i) when you use certain features on our site
```

The problem I'm having is with my counters and the second level, 1.1, 1.2 etc
This is the CSS I have so far, I've attached the rendered results and the example from the word doc I'm trying to emulate

```
.privacy-policy-list {
    counter-reset: item;
}

.privacy-policy-list li li:before {
    counter-increment: item;
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

.privacy-policy-list ol li ol li {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha !important;
    padding-left: 5em;
}

.privacy-policy-list ol li ol li ol li{
    list-style-type: lower-roman !important;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would be grateful for your help to point me in the right direction, thanks

[image: List style formatting from Word]

Comment: please provide your html too - see [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a four level `ol`, you need to change the list style type of the third and fourth levels `ol` and remove the content of the pseudo element on the `li` from them:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}

ol ol ol li::before {
  content: '';                         /* remove third level content (probably better to give a class to the third level ol rather than using this selector) */
}

ol ol ol {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;        /* set third level to alpha (probably better to give a class to these ol rather than using this selector) */
}

ol ol ol ol {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;        /* set fourth level to roman (probably better to give a class to these ol rather than using this selector) */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Collection of information
    <ol>
      <li>
        For the purposes outlined in Clause 2, we may collect and process the following information about you:
        <ol>
          <li>
            Information you give us
            <ol>
              <li>when you report any problem to us</li>
              <li>when you use certain features on our site</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Collection of information
    <ol>
      <li>
        For the purposes outlined in Clause 2, we may collect and process the following information about you:
        <ol>
          <li>
            Information you give us
            <ol>
              <li>when you report any problem to us</li>
              <li>when you use certain features on our site</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I'm after, With your help I've learnt a lot today about list styles, css counters and css selectors, Thank you very much