# How to indent sub sub bullets in HTML?

Tags: html, css, list, indentation, numbered-list

I want something like this where a main bullet point has a sub bullet and that sub bullet has another sub bullet and the sub-bullet need to be indented

[image: this is what I want]

Instead I end up like this
[image: this is what I get]

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <p>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <u> I am first bullet </u> <br> <br>
                </li>
             <span>1.1 I am a sub bullet</span> <br> <br>
                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 1.1.1 I am a sub - sub - bullet for 1.1. I have more points below me. Feel free check out my other siblings. 
                I go more than three to five lines of copy, because i have a lot to express, say, communicate with the audience. I could be lorem ipsum, 
                i could be a story line or i could be a content for educating students, businesses, doctors, lawyers, executives. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet 
                consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, eaque distinctio. Eaque magni voluptatum, reiciendis mollitia ut doloremque laudantium tenetur sapiente 
                adipisci iure esse numquam temporibus dignissimos laboriosam, laborum excepturi.
                 </span>     
        </ol>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want sub-lists, make lists within a list item (i.e. `<ol><li>Bullet<ol><li>Sub-bullet<ol><li>Sub-sub-bullet</li></ol></li></ol></li></ol>`)

Comment: Nest your lists, and use CSS to configure outline numbering. Good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405945/html-ordered-list-1-1-1-2-nested-counters-and-scope-not-working

Comment: Thank you Heretic & Tim