# how to add sub levels in html

Tags: html

I am trying to add sublevels in tab document but when i am trying it canat be add 
the code is

```
 <li><a href="support.html"><span>DOCUMNETS</span></a>
     <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Upload Dcoument</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Approved Document</a></li>
            </ul>
```

when i am trying this it cant be done

any help?

Comment: Try to add </li> to the end. See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050843/present-lists-and-sublists-in-html

Comment: yes i add but during code pasting it misses but i add in my app

Comment: please define " can't be done ", code with the last </li> is valid, maybe javascript/css related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_nestedlists2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h4>A nested List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
    <li>Black tea</li>
    <li>Green tea
      <ul>
      <li>China</li>
      <li>Africa</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

You probably forgot to close some tags. Use some editor that helps you with tags in HTML. Notepad++, free Visual Studio editions, ... there are many...

**UPDATE:**
Indent your code and you will see more easily by yourself next time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <li>
    <a href="support.html"><span>DOCUMNETS</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-level">
      <li><a href="#">Upload Dcoument</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Approved Document</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</body>
</html>
```