# Need an ol/li to show 1.1

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Achieving sub numbering on ol items html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058564/achieving-sub-numbering-on-ol-items-html)
>   [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, …) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

I need a list to show numbers as 1.1 and not 1.

Basically, is there a way in css/html to make a list show numbers made like x.x or x.x.x ? I know there's an argument to make it roman numbers ( I, II, III, VI, V ) or letters ( a, b, c, d, e ) but can you make the ol/li show as sub numbers ( 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 )?

Comment: possible deplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Sorry about the duplicate tho.