# How to achieve following list layout via markup?

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Achieving sub numbering on ol items html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058564/achieving-sub-numbering-on-ol-items-html)

I'm trying to achieve something like this by using unordered list:

**1. Title**

Objective: some text here...

1.1 option1 
     1.2 option2 
     1.3 option3

**2. Title**

Objective: some text here...

2.1 option1 
     2.2 option2 
     2.3 option3

---

I tried using `list-style: decimal;` but that only achieves numbers like 1, 2, 3 etc whereas I need them to have format of 1.2 , 1.3 ... 2.1 ,2.3 etc. Also is this achievable by using one unordered list or will I need to use several?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects, I used this code ([demo](http://www.codepen.io/yardenst/pen/KDcLI))

(I don't remember where did I get it from, but it works)

```
ol{ 
    counter-reset: listing ;
}
li { 
    display: block ;
}
li:before { 
    content: counters(listing, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: listing ;
}
```

This method gives you controller over many other things of course: you can customize the counter as you pleased using the `content` property

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible. See here all `list-style` possible types http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_all

Answer (score 0):

i think there might be browser compatibility issues with counter property in css.

Why not use jquery?

```
<style type="text/css">
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>    

<ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
</ul>


<script>
var num = 1.0;
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
    var text = $(this).text();
     index++;

     list = num + (index / 10);

     $(this).html(list + " . " + text);

});
</script>
```