# Add a "." after li numbering

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list that I have incrementing by 1. What I am trying to do is get it to increment by 1 with a dot after the 1:

```
1.
2.
3.
4
```

Within my list I have it working like,

```
1
 1.1
 1.2
 1.3
2
 2.1
 2.2
3
 3.1
 3.2
 3.3
```

So that Is correct I just want the number  at the beginning to also have a . at the end.

My current code looks something like this:

```css
ol { 
  counter-reset: item ;
}

li { 
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> 
    <ol>

    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

So it should end up looking like:

```
1.
 1.1
 1.2
 1.3
2.
 2.1
 2.2
 2.3
3.
 3.1
 3.2
 3.3
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: For the people marking as duplicate or putting links to guides. This guy has a very specific problem. Read first, then comment or answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/nj591yf3/) of what you want.

All I did was change the CSS so that the ordered-list-items have a period at the end, unless they're deeper than 1 level. Fairly simple.

```
ol li::before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
}

ol ol li::before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

No need for extra, unnecessary classes.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you want the numbers to have a dot at the end change your css to

```
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ".\00a0 ";
}
```

[image: Codepen]

`\00a0` adds space (`" "` doesn't worked for me).

**Edit:** Regarding the discussion: give an extra class to the first level and use above CSS (see Codepen).

[image: Codepen]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOOjv

Answer (score 0):

There is already a topic solving this issue

**[Achieving sub numbering on ol items html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058564/achieving-sub-numbering-on-ol-items-html)**

Credits to [**Joey**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)

```css
ol { counter-reset: item }
ol>li { display: block }
ol>li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> 
        Tome 1
        <ol>
          <li>Chapter 1</li>
          <li>Chapter 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @zertops  yes I know you can do it like that. But if you look there it then becomes 1.1. which I do not want. I just want it to have a 1. followed by 1.1 then 1.2 etc

Comment: @factordog You should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: I did. I explained how it looked and where I wanted to add a .

Comment: @factordog No, you didn't. "I just want the number at the beginning to also have a . at the end" is totally ambiguous.

Comment: Apologies then. But that was what I was trying to get at

Comment: Misunderstood it, too. It's also not good looking because it's inconsequent design (speaking as TeX fan). I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol { 
  counter-reset: item ;
}

li { 
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") "."; 
  counter-increment: item;
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Test1
    <ol>
      <li>Test1.1</li>
      <li>Test1.2</li>
      <li>Test1.3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Test2</li>
  <li>Test3</li>
</ol>
```

I've amended the snippet above.  You simply needed to add a "." in the second part of the "content" attribute.  I also stuck a margin in there to make it obvious.